# Latency of 10G fiber SFP+

Tags: cisco, network, sfp

I'm optimizing network stack for latency.  We were using SFP+ with fiber than we came to know that Direct Attach Cables (DAC) have lower latency as there is no SFP involve [Link](https://www.arista.com/assets/data/pdf/Copper-Faster-Than-Fiber-Brief.pdf). We are measuring wire to wire latency using hardware timestamps, But we are not able to see any difference between DAC cable and SFP+ with fiber.

I have searched the internet but I'm not able to find typical latency of 10G SFP+. The only [link](https://www.datacenterknowledge.com/archives/2012/11/27/data-center-infrastructure-benefits-of-deploying-sfp-fiber-vs-10gbase-t) I'm able to find is almost 10years old.

Can anyone confirm what is typical latency of SFP+ or how to calculate it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Latency of 10GBASE-SR/-LR vs SFP+ DAC is very closely the same - in contrast to 10GBASE-T which adds appr. 1.5 μs.

Majorly, latency is caused by the line encoding overhead. In the case of -R PHYs, that's 64b66b code which requires little processing. SFP+ cages are directly fed with an -R data stream, which DACs then couple onto copper twinax and SFP+ modules use to modulate their lasers. Again, very little processing, same low latency for both.

Hypothetically, DAC *could* be faster because of the potentially higher velocity factor (VF) and, accordingly, lower propagation delay. The kind of twinax used is at the vendor's discretion, but even if that had a VF of .9 in comparison to fiber's .67, the delay difference for a long DAC of 10 m against fiber would be around 12 ns (10 / c * [1/VF<sub>fiber</sub> - 1/VF<sub>twinax</sub>]).

It makes more sense to tailor the patch cables than to worry about that (12 ns is about 2.5 m worth of fiber) but either is rather moot.